# PHP: filter string to work as a function name

Tags: php, string, variables, filtering

what is a quick way to filter a string to work as a function name?

note: I'm thinking something like filter_var().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be looking for

- [`is_callable`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.is-callable.php) —  Verify that the contents of a variable can be called as a function

> Verify that the contents of a variable can be called as a function. This can check that a simple variable contains the name of a valid function, or that an array contains a properly encoded object and function name.

If you just want to make sure the supplied value is valid syntax for a function name, you can set the second argument `$syntax_only` to `TRUE`:

> **syntax_only:** If set to TRUE the function only verifies that name might be a function or method. It will only reject simple variables that are not strings, or an array that does not have a valid structure to be used as a callback. The valid ones are supposed to have only 2 entries, the first of which is an object or a string, and the second a string.

Comment: in php first you make your own function to do something, and then you find out that php had this function built in all along!

Comment: is there a function like is_callable that turns a dirty name into a valid one?

Answer (score 1):

From the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php):

> As a regular expression, it would be
>   expressed thus:
>   [a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*

So, something like this, maybe?

```
function can_be_function($var) {
  return preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*$/', $var);
}
```

Comment: Emil, it looks like I misunderstood the question. Thanks for providing this.

Comment: can this be made into a preg_replace so that the variable gets turned INTO a name that can be called as a function?